# Set Datetime format - C# 

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date

I have the following property within a user control:

```
    public DateTime? Value 
        { 
        get 
        {
            return DatePickerInput.SelectedDate; 
        } 
        set 
        { 
            DatePickerInput.SelectedDate = value; 
        } 
    }
```

This selects dates in the following format `01-Feb-2012`. I want to change the format so it returns dates in the format `dd/MM/yy`...how is this possible?

Comment: do not confuse UI rendering of the value with real object value, the DateTime field will always have the correct value then it's only about how you render it on the controls or User Interface. Try to call Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy") and you should get what you want, at least in debug...

Comment: You should set wanted format in your control (UI).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It uses the current culture settings on your computer. If you want that format you need to return it as a string or let your receiving method convert it to string. For example:

```
string myFormat = Value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

I did not take into account that your Value property can also return null value. This is just to show you how to format the result.

Answer (score 1):

`DateTime?` (i.e. `Nullable<DateTime>`) does not have implicit formatting. You'll need to format the value in whatever UI you're working with or change your property (or add a new one) to return a `String` value instead:

```
public String FormattedValue {
    get {
        return DatePickerInput.SelectedDate.HasValue
            ? DatePickerInput.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("dd/MM/yy")
            : ""; // return an empty string if SelectedDate is null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The DateTime property itself doesn't carry a specific format - it's a neutral representation of the datetime. It's the input control's format that you should be setting. The DateTimeInput control probably has a "FormatString" property, but that depends on the control. Are you using WPF? ASP.NET? WinForms?

Answer (score 1):

#### Description

A DateTime has no `format` but you can change the Display Format using the `CustomFormat` property.

By default the display format depends on the `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture`.

#### Sample

```
myDateTimePicker.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
myDateTimePicker.CustomFormat = "dd/MM/yy";
```

#### More Information

- [MSDN - DateTimePicker.CustomFormat Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.customformat.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The datatype you're returning - DateTime - itself doesn't 'have' a format. I'd suggest leaving it to your caller for decide on the formatting, or implement an additional property that returns a string and formats according to your wishes.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Microsoft document: [Standard Data and Time Format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx).